# Search mysql database for date range

Tags: php

I have a database where users enter a date, among other things, with a drop down calendar, the date format is in this format   21-NOV-2012 .
Is there a way to search the database with a date range ?
I currently search date using the following ::

```
sql ="SELECT * FROM ircb WHERE  date LIKE '%$term1%' AND date LIKE '%$term2%'  LIMIT $start_from, 15";
```

term1 is month and term 2 is year , this does not allow for date range within the month only for the month.
any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you not store the dates with a temporal datatype?  If not, you need to rethink the design.

Comment: It also looks like your month and year fields might not even be integers. You *really* need to rethink the design in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't really solve your problem but I guess it's a testing (and you have access to the database) and will risk myself of getting flamed by telling you a better approach, as I will feel guilty if don't tell you what would be the correct way to do it:

You should have a Date type field in your database (I assume mysql) and store the whole date in that field, and mysql can search using that date (normally the standard date format would be YYYY-MM-DD) .

You just need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date > 'your date';
or ........................... < 'your date';
or .................WHERE date BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2';
```

It will allow you to do those kind of operations in a much easier and human-readable way.

Also have a look at the [datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) if you are interested, as you can do the same but with the time of that day also included in the same field! :D

Have a good look at the field types, as it's essential to have the database healthy and optimized.

Comment: sounds great will have a go, first suggestion of using BETWEEN didn't work, my date is obtained using date picker in previously indicated format, value is stored in database in a field I called cdate which is set as  ::cdate   varchar(40)  latin1_swedish_ci No, I ssume then that this field is incorrect , thanks

Comment: No, the type you are using there is varchar, look for "date"

Comment: ok, changed the table field to date and the default values indicated are  0000-00-00  , how do I now use a date picker to properly insert these values?

Comment: What date picker are you using? It should be pretty easy to change the format to YYYY-MM-DD format, have a quick look on the documentation or google for it

Comment: great managed to properly set field as date, and format is correct and I edited datepicker to capture date in proper format, date is now entering into databse properly

Comment: can you now look at the code and see if the "entering the date range is correct... here is what I have, on the enter page :::::Start Date: <input type="text" name="term1" style="background-color:#FFFF11">
<br />
<br />

End Date: <input type="text" name="term2" style="background-color:#FFFF11">    ::::should the type be set as "text"

Comment: and on the search I have ::::   $term1 = $_REQUEST['term1'];
$term2 = $_REQUEST['term2'];


$terms= '&term1='.$term1 . '&term2='.$term2;

$limit=15;

$sql ="SELECT * FROM ircb WHERE cdate  BETWEEN '%$term1%' AND '%$term2%'  LIMIT $start_from, 15";


$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ircb WHERE cdate  BETWEEN '%$term1%' AND '%$term2%'");

Comment: Yes the input type is text, and the code I can't understand some parts of it but seems like it would work. Anyway I recommend you not using $_REQUEST but $_POST and $_GET a bit, google a bit and you can find out easily the "how" and "why"s.

Answer (score 0):

```
 date >= '$term2-$term1-01' AND date < DATE_ADD( '$term2-$term1-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: sorry, how do I post the code in proper format in the response box?

Comment: does not seem to work, terms are entered , I echo them to make sure they are passed and they are.  However  "SELECT * FROM ircb WHERE cdate > '%term1%'   ends up giving all results , if I use BETWEEN TERM1 and TERM2 no results are returned

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
sql ="SELECT * FROM ircb WHERE date BETWEEN '$term1' AND '$term2' LIMIT $start_from, 15";
```

`BETWEEN` will let you fetch the range date, and you can delete those `LIKE`.

Comment: <td style="width: 472px">
<input type=text name="cdate" id="Inputfield"  size=40 style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66; width: 270px;">
</td>      here is what the input field on my webpage looks like for date insert with datepicker